# how to remove an array of div's with the same id using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am echoing an array in php:

```
foreach ($array as $print) {

$var = $print['var'];   

<div id=post>echo $var;</div>

}
```

I have a function that removes this div if a user posts a new comment:

```
$("#post").remove();
```

However this will only remove 1 div with the id=post, I need to remove all of them, Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Don't use duplicate id's.

Comment: first of all, you should not assign the same ID to all your DIV's. It's called IDentifier with a purpose...

Comment: I am using infinite scroll, adding $i++ to each div id breaks the scroll

Comment: then you should consider using something else, and not ID's for this task

Comment: like child divs or class names or something like this...

Comment: you see.. this is what I do... I inspire others to answer :)))

Comment: @user3312792 I wouldn't expect any plugin to *require* you to use duplicate id's. If it isn't working with id+index, you're likely using it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should use `class` instead of `id`.

```
foreach ($array as $print) {
    $var = $print['var'];
    echo '<div class="post">'.$var.'</div>';
}
```

To remove all the elements by `post class`

```
$(".post").remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is never a case where it makes sense to use duplicate id's on an html page. It's invalid, and no one should ever do it.

that said, you can solve this by using the attribute equals selector if you must use duplicate id's (which again, makes no sense.)

```
$('[id="post"]').remove();
```

The better solution of course would be to NOT use duplicate ID's, and instead use a selector based on whatever alternative you use.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned ID's need to be unique, instead use classes.

```
<div class='post'>echo $var;</div>
```

And then

```
$(".post").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id.

```
foreach ($array as $print) {
   $var = $print['var'];   
   echo "<div class='post'>".$var."</div>";
}

$(".post").remove();
```